# Android TextView doesn't show affected text

Tags: android, textview

Ok so... I've been trying to affect text to TextView (because it's meant to show text, right?)
But for some unknown to me reason it refuses to print whatever I put into it.

My application has two activities, the MainAcivity, or a welcoming screen, per se, and a GameActivity (the project is a Domino game).

I create my previously written java objects at the beginning of the GameActivity class, trying then to show player's name within a TextView.

```
Player player1 = new Player("Hulk");
```

creates a player with name Hulk, as you can imagine. I have a method within Player.java to return player's name:

```
player1.getName()
```

returns string "Hulk"

I then try to set my TextView's text to hulk, first off by creating a handle to it with:

```
TextView p1v = (TextView) findViewById(R.textviews.p1view);
```

then doing the following:

```
p1v.setText("Player 1 : " + player1.toString());
```

the p1view is defined as follows within game.xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
 ...
   <LinearLayout
 ...
         <TextView
            android:id="@+textviews/p1view"
            android:text="Board"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried p1view.textAppend, tried using android:editable="true". Nothing seems to work.

Funnily enough though, when I try doing the same thing, within MainActivity, it works, as so: 
public class

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

with the TextView defined within main.xml as follows:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+textviews/mainview_player"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
```

Following are the full codes of the files, just to avoid answers like: Give us the full code D:

GameActivity.java:

> package domino.asd;
>
> import LI260.*; import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class GameActivity extends Activity {
>
> ```
> private Player player1 = new Player("HULK");
> private Player player2 = new Player("CPU");
> private Pioche bag = new Pioche();
> private Plateau board = new Plateau();
> private Game game1 = new Game(bag, board, player1, player2);
> TextView p1name = null;
> TextView p2name = null;
>
> /**
>  * Called when the activity is first created.
>  *
>  * @param savedInstanceState
>  */
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.game);
>     TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.textviews.p1view);
>     tv.setText(player1.getName());
> }    }
> ```

game.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:weightSum="10"

>
    <!-- Played layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+drawable/gameview_Scores"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+buttons/exitButton"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+buttons/drawButton"
            android:text="Draw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+buttons/scoresButton"
            android:text="Show scores"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Board layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+textviews/gameview_Table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
        android:background="#ffff00"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+textviews/p1view"
            android:text="Board"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- At hand layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+drawable/gameview_Playable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#ff00ff"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+textviews/gameview_AtHandText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package domino.asd;

import LI260.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Player p1 = new Player("Hulk");
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView p1view = (TextView) findViewById(R.textviews.mainview_player);
        p1view.setText(p1.getName());
    }

    public void btnClick_Name(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == R.buttons.B_EnterName) {
            EditText playersname = (EditText) findViewById(R.string.playerNameInput);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your name: " + playersname.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.game);
    }
}
```

and lastly main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+string/playerNameInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+textviews/mainview_player"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+buttons/B_EnterName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Save name and start game."
        android:onClick="btnClick_Name"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You seem to have done everything except tell us what the problem is.

Comment: There's no need to swear.

Comment: The problem is, I want to show the player1's name in my GameActivity, where it won't show, contrarily to MainActivity, where I don't need it to show, and it does :<

Comment: Please think about this.  "It won't show".  I'll spend 15 seconds thinking about some of the many possible meanings.  It shows nothing?  It show the wrong name?  It shows a piece of text from somewhere else in the code?  Shall I continue?

Comment: It just prints nothing at all, whatsoever, sir. No text at all is displayed, in there place (TextView p1view) I expected it to be.

Comment: So you expect `p1View`, in your main activity, to show the players name returned by `player.getName()`?  This line of text, `p1view.setText(p1.getName());` results in p1View being blank?

Comment: I actually expect p1View, in my GameActivity, to show the player's name returned by player.getName() (which should be Hulk), and yes, it is blank.

Comment: Merlin has the right idea.  You need to do some tutorials.  You haven't even declared p1View in your game activity so not sure what you are trying to achieve at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are first loading the activity, you are calling this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView p1view = (TextView) findViewById(R.textviews.mainview_player);
p1view.setText(p1.getName());
```

Yet when the user click's the button you are only calling this code:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

Because you have reset the main content view the child view mainview_player has been destroyed and replaced with a new one when inflated from R.layout.game.

You would need to call this code again to find the new view in the game layout and populate it with your player name:

```
TextView p1view = (TextView) findViewById(R.textviews.mainview_player);
p1view.setText(p1.getName());
```

You would be better to look into how activities relate to one another and start a new activity for R.layout.game

Comment: Good spot.  I missed that!

Comment: R.layout.game has its own activity, the GameActivity.java handles it. This is exactly where I want the TextView to show player's name (and it doesn't).
I only added it within MainActivity to show it works there, and not within GameActivity, where I want it to.

Comment: Then you need to use startActivity with an Intent and use Intent.putStringExtra to pass it to the GameActivity class ... then pick it up using Context.getData() to grab the intent on the other side and call Intent.getStringExtra() to extract the string from the intent

Comment: That actually answers a different question I had, on how to pass them in between the two, thank you. 

I'm unable to print any text from GameActivity.
As you can see I'm picking this inside GameActivity: 
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.textviews.p1view);
tv.setText(player1.getName());
p1view is a TextView defined in game.xml, GameActivity is responsible for this one. And the text still won't display within that field.

When I do the same within MainActivity,with:
TextView p1view = (TextView) findViewById(R.textviews.mainview_player);
        p1view.setText(p1.getName()); it works.Why?